# htaccess rewrite not working with ampersand in url path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to rewrite paths that contain **&favtitle=** removing everything after and including the string.

Eg. **/author/firstname-surname&favtitle=Firstname%20Surname** rewritten to **/author/firstname-surname**

I have a RewriteRule in an htaccess file but it does not rewrite the path:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)(&|%26|%2526)favtitle=.*$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

On a local dev copy of the site on a Windows PC this htaccess RewriteRule works. It also works on another copy of the site on shared Linux web hosting. But it does not work on our production server on AWS.

The server is Amazon Linux AMI running Apache 2.2.29

Do I have this RewriteRule correct? And if so what might be stopping it working on the AWS server?

I'm pretty sure the & in the path is the problem as a RewriteRule that targets a string before the ampersand works on the AWS server.
Eg.

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)-surname.*$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

**/author/firstname-surname&favtitle=Firstname%20Surname** rewrites to **/author/firstname**

Any ideas as to why this is occurring?